IS THIS PUZZLE ABSURD?
The answer to this puzzle is a word. Good Luck!
314159165058270828182841173100080756101121356237161803198870(+1)



Hint

 WOWOW in the comments has got most of the numbers correctly and has spotted that there is some kind of ‘twist’ to them. There are 2 hints subtly incorporated in the puzzle to help find all the numbers. Also pay attention to those ‘twists’ what details do they all have in common?

Hint 2

 Part of the rebus and the title I am referring to in hint 1!


Gur ahzore frrzf gb unir fbzrguvat gb qb jvgu zngurzngvpny pbafgnagf. Gur svefg 12 qvtvgf zngpu gur qvtvgf bs CV naq gur sbyybjvat 11 qvtvgf zngpu gur qvtvgf bs Rhyre'f pbafgnag ohg jvgu n gjvfg. Bar qvtvg bs rnpu frpgvba vf bar yrff guna va gur pbeerfcbaqvat ahzore. (V thrff gur +1 vf fnlvat gung nqqvat 1 gb bar bs gur qvtvgf vf arprffnel)

@WOWOW Lbh pregnvayl ner irel zhpu ba gur evtug genpx jryy qbar!! Keep going!

I have a list of all of them and I've been searching for nearly an hour, yet I can't seem to find the next one. At first I though it's the rot13(Gurbqbehf' pbafgnag) but the extra 1 disproves that. I did find rot13(gur Tbyqra Engvb) near the end though.

I think the answer is

IRRATIONAL!!

Which is certainly absurd!


To start:

The string at the top, partially identified by WOWOW in the comments, contains a list of various irrational numbers. However each of them has 2 digits that are different:

3.14159165058
3.14159265358 = PI

2.70828182841
2.71828182845 = E

1.73100080756
1.73205080756 = ROOT 3

1.01121356237
1.41421356237 = ROOT 2

1.61803198870
1.61803398874 = GOLDEN RATIO

Next we have

A grid...

We have pairs of numbers from the string - so perhaps these are coordinates?

@Tobbs found that by filling in the grid with the first 25 letters of the alphabet, and taking the numbers as coordinates - where the number replaced with 0 is the x coordinate and the number replaced with 1 is the y coordinate we get:

(3,2), (1,5), (5, 2), (4,1), (4, 3)
R, A, T, I, N



However, note there is a (+1) on the end of the golden ratio digits at the top. In fact, applying this to the final coordinate gives us (5,3) instead which would be 'O' - giving us the word RATIO

Now

We apply the rebus:

The question mark represents the word RATIO which we just found making the rebus:

E+ RATIO 0

Pronouncing '0' as 'Null' (thanks @Tobbs) and sounding it out we get the word:

'ERATIONULL'

Or in English: IRRATIONAL!!!


I got to a similar point with this. I was hoping to find rot13(gjragl svir mrebf naq barf gb svyy gur tevq pbzcyrgryl jvgu fbzr ovanel ebjf, ohg jvgu gur +1 ng gur raq gurer'f fgvyy bayl gjragl sbhe). The significance of 'absurd' is that a rot13('fheq' vf nabgure anzr sbe na veengvbany ahzore).

@Stiv yeah thats probably all there is to absurd - still not sure at all on twists though

Good work so far things are looking great. The next  step is to just interpret the grid correctly, I am sure you will get it!

rot13(Zl thrff jbhyq or gb hfr n Cbylovhf fdhner, naq svaq yrggref onfrq ba gur pbbeqvangrf tvira va gur pbeerpg veengvbany ahzore. Gur zbfg jbeq-yvxr V pna sbez guvf jnl vf 'URXGB'... Nyfb, rirel gvzr gjb qvtvgf gung punatrq gb 0 naq 1. Znlor gung vaqvpngrf vaqrkvat va fbzr sbez?)

@Beastly Gerbil I will make an edit soon to make the puzzle a little less obscure it was something I intended to include initially but I thought it might make the puzzle a little too easy, we’ll see.

@PDT stumped atm so will have to see if anyone else gets it!

Continuing from others' observations:  rot13(Vs gur tevq vf svyyrq jvgu gur svefg 25 yrggref bs gur nycunorg, naq gur pbbeqvangrf ner [ahzore ercynprq ol mreb], [ahzore ercynprq ol bar], vg fcryyf 'engva'. Gur +1 pbhyq or hfrq ba gur ynfg pbbeqvangr gb znxr 'engvb'.)

@Tobbs aha, and on top of that I think that potentially could be the final answer as the rebus is perhaps rot13('Engr' (gur R+) + ? (abg fher ubj guvf yvaxf lrg) + 'B')

@PDT I have tentatively guessed at the answer, I'm not entirely 100% but hopefully the right idea

I'm thinking that in the rebus: rot13(mreb ercerfragf ahyy)

Ok this is very close!! Keep on going!

@PDT think I got it!

Ah yes congrats!! I was intending nil but null is actually better so we will keep it!!
